# Name of x-axis and changing colour

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

Here is my data set:

```
structure(list(Resort = c("Park City", "Powder Mountain", "Snowbird", 
"Alta", "Snow Basin", "Deer Valley"), `Named Runs` = c(348, 154, 140, 116, 107, 103)), 
row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is the code I have pieced together. I was wondering if someone could help me change the name of the x-axis label while keeping my reorder correct? I was also wanted to change the colour. Thanks!

````
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

        Utah_ski_resort_data_ <- read_excel("Desktop/Utah ski resort data..xlsx")

        View(Utah_ski_resort_data_)

        table(Utah_ski_resort_data_$Resort)
        table(Utah_ski_resort_data_$`Named Runs`)


        Utah_ski_resort_data_ <- structure(list(Resort = c("Park City", "Powder Mountain", 
        "Snowbird", 
                                                   "Alta", "Snow Basin", "Deer Valley", 
        "Solitude", "Brian Head", "Brighton", "Beaver Mountain", "Sundance", "Eagle Point", 
        "Nordic Valley"), `Named Runs` = c(348, 154, 140, 116, 107, 103, 82, 71, 66, 48, 44, 40, 
        23)), 
                                   row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
        "data.frame"))
        Utah_ski_resort_data_ %>% 
           ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Resort, -`Named Runs`), y = `Named Runs`)) +
           geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
         theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
Utah_ski_resort_data_ %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Resort, -`Named Runs`), y = `Named Runs`)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1,
                                   colour = 'cornflowerblue'),
        axis.title.x = element_text(colour = 'deeppink'))+
  labs(x='My name')
```

Output:

[image]